# What is a "marker protocol" in Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols, terminology

I was searching through some Swift open source code and have now seen the term "marker protocol" pop up twice. From context I'm inferring it as a protocol that exists for code readability reasons, not actually to enforce rules. Can anyone explain exactly what a "marker protocol" is AND why it is used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Marker protocol is a design pattern borrowed from other object-oriented programming languages that allow protocols or interfaces. The idea is to mark a class for use in a specific way, but without requiring the class to provide any functionality by implementing specific methods. For example, Java used this approach to mark classes *serializable*.

Here is an example:

```
protocol Marker {}

class One : Marker {
    ...
}
class Two { // No marker
    ...
}
...
if (myObj is Marker) {
    ... // Objects of class One will pass
    ... // Objects of class Two will not pass
}
```

This technique is becoming less relevant when the need to mark classes is addressed explicitly by language. For example, Java could have used *annotations* for dealing with serializability, in the same way that C# did it using *attributes*, but the feature had not been available at the time.

Swift is an evolving language that has attributes, but all of them are pre-defined. An addition of user-defined attributes will eliminate the need for marker protocols.